# How to change process name in C#

Tags: c#

I have multiple processes that running at the same time of my C# program and all of this processes have the same name.

I am trying to give specific name to each process running of this program using a function.

Comment: Processes don't have names, they are the name of the executable you're running, plus any arguments you pass to it, along with environment information.

Comment: Where do you want to store this "name", in memory of your application? Would a simple map (dictionary) work?

Comment: @gunr2171 yes right how can I give different name for each process of them

Comment: @gunr2171I xan pass the name as a string parameter using  a function

Comment: Something like `string name = "p" + p++;` where p is an `int` that is increased whenever you create a name like p0, p1, p2, ...

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes yes can you translate it as code to understand the idea

Comment: This just creates a name. I am not sure what you want to do with this name, as you cannot give the [Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process) itself a name. It is given a process id by the operating system. If you just want to give it a name inside of your application you can use the dictionary  approach as suggested by @gunr2171

Answer (score 1):

You're looking to do some sort of lookup, a Dictionary is a good tool for that.

```
Dictionary<string, Process> processNames = new();
```

Add and remove entries just like any other Dictionary.

```
Process p = ...
processNames.Add("myprocess", p);
```

then look it up by it's name

```
Process p2 = processNames["myprocess"];
```

You can populate `p` with `Process.Start`, or any other "GetProcess*" static methods in the Process class (`Process.GetProcessById`, `Process.GetProcessesByName`, etc).

Answer (score 0):

You will want to rename your project in order to change the process name. Process names are just the names of the executable file being run. Whenever you build, the main resulting file will be the same as the project name. Take a look:

[image: Photo of processes]

One thing you could do is to track processes that you created using a hash set or dictionary if you are doing anything that involves requiring the Process object of that specific process.